# Javascript function default parameter incorrect

Tags: javascript

Why does the code at this JS fiddle not work?  I want it to log a blank string, but it's logging a Pointer Event.
https://jsfiddle.net/wvom7k2f/

```
let c = document.getElementById('c');
c.onclick = test;

function test(a='', b=''){
console.log(a);
}
```

Comment: the first parameter to all events is the `Event` object itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An onclick event handler will put the event as the first parameter.  If you want to call test with no parameters you should change c.onclick = test; to the following:

```
c.onclick = () => test();
```

Comment: How does this answer his question? `I want it to log a blank string`

Comment: @maksymiuk That’s what the default parameters in the question are for.

Comment: @maksymiuk - By assigning a function to `onclick` that, when called, will call `test` with no arguments, triggering the default parameter value (which is a blank string).

Comment: His test function will do that.

Comment: @maksymiuk The function `test()` is defined as `function test(a='', b='')`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I stand corrected, I somehow misinterpreted the code, and I retract my dislike

Comment: @maksymiuk - We've all done that kind of thing. :-) (You can remove the comment, too, if you like.)

Answer (score 3):

You're doing `c.onclick = test`.  The [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) event calls its function with the event as the 1st parameter.

Try to do:

```
function test(e, a='', b='') {
    console.log(a);
}

c.onclick = test;
```

Or, if you don't want to change `test()`, then you can do:

```
function test(a='', b='') {
    console.log(a);
}

c.onclick = function(e) {
    test();
};
```

Comment: Makes sense.  So what would be the proper way to do it if I want to also call that function elsewhere, such as test('foo', 'bar')?

Comment: @user568551 I added a 2nd block of code.  You could do `c.onclick = function() { test(); }`.

Comment: Or check [Josh Cronin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71084094/206403).